# XQuery: create a new sequence and return it

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

What I am trying to achieve is to add values from `$stationsSequence` into a new sequence, `$newSequence` and then return `distinct-values` in the sequence. I "naively" tried to do it with an if statement like this:

```
let $stationsSequence := fn:doc("stations.xml")//station
let $newSequence := ()

for $station in $stationsSequence 

    return

        if ( fn:starts-with($station, "W") or fn:starts-with($station, "B") )
        then
            fn:insert-before($newSequence , last(), $station)
        else ()

        fn:distinct-values($newSequence)
```

What would be the correct way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: You didn't add a problem statement. What's the issue with your approach? Please _always_ include the error message or describe why you consider the code broken.

Comment: Apart from the general problem that you're trying to write as if you were using a procedural language, note that last() doesn't mean what you think it means, and that the best way to append B at the end of A is with the expression (A, B) rather than using insert-before().

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update a variable in XQuery, because the variables are immutable. That is to say that:

```
let $s := ()
return
    let $s1 := fn:insert-before($s, last(), "a")
    let $s2 := fn:insert-before($s, last(), "b")
    return
        $s2
```

Gives the result:

```
("b")
```

Instead you have to create a new variable which contains your old value and your new value, and then repeat that until you have all your values.

However, I think the simplest solution to your problem is most likely:

```
fn:distinct-values(
    fn:doc("stations.xml")//station[fn:substring(., 1, 1) = ("W", "B")]
)
```

Comment: I'm puzzled by your example:  neither my mental parser nor any XQuery engine I have tried returns "b" -- instead, they raise a syntax error over the lack of a '`return` clause in the nested FLWOR expression.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Yes, of course you are correct :-) Sorry I forgot the final return in the example

Comment: Whew, that's a relief.